# How to simulate click on menu hardwarebutton with espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

following question: I want to simulate a click on the menu hardwarebutton. Is it possible with espresso to do this (If yes - a code snippet would be nice)?

Comment: Espresso.openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

Comment: works perfect - however couldnt just copy and paste because i got an encoding error ;)

Comment: Then I'll write it as an answer instead ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Espresso.openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(getActivity().getApplicationContext(‌​));
```